# Make image follow mouse with ease in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working in a HTLM5 Canvas where I'm trying to make an image follow mouse cursor with some ease. The problem is every time I move the mouse the image position is reset to origin (I believe). I wanted to keep actual position and from there move to mouse new position.

Here is my code:

```js
var AN = AN || {};

pic = new Image();

AN.initialize = function() {
  //listen to mouse behavior and read every time he moves
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", AN.moveMouse, false);
  //load canvas
  cv = $('#canvas')[0];
  canvas = cv.getContext('2d');
  //load image
  pic.src = "http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/349/b/e/i_hate_you__i_love_you__zoro_x_reader__by_riseagainstevil-d88ovwj.png";
};


AN.moveMouse = function(e) {

  //get mouse position
  var xPos = e.clientX;
  var yPos = e.clientY;

  var position = getPosition(pic);

  var x = xPos - pic.width / 2; //final position
  var y = yPos - pic.height / 2; //final position
  var t = 0; //0-1, this is what you change in animation loop
  var tx = position.x; //actual position of element for x
  var ty = position.y; //actual position of element for y

  function myLoop() {

    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

    tx = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * x;
    ty = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * y;

    //if you need Y then do the same for that (ty)

    // set element by tx
    canvas.drawImage(pic, tx, ty, pic.width, pic.height);
    position = getPosition(pic);

    if (t < 1) {
      t += 0.01; //determines speed
      requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
      //setTimeout(myLoop, 16); //option to above
    }
  }
  myLoop();
};

EasingFunctions = {
  linear: function(t) {
    return t;
  },
  easeInQuad: function(t) {
    return t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t * (2 - t);
  },
  easeInOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
  },
  easeInCubic: function(t) {
    return t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutCubic: function(t) {
    return (--t) * t * t + 1;
  },
  easeInOutCubic: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1;
  },
  easeInQuart: function(t) {
    return t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuart: function(t) {
    return 1 - (--t) * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInOutQuart: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInQuint: function(t) {
    return t * t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuint: function(t) {
    return 1 + (--t) * t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInOutQuint: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t;
  }
}

function getPosition(element) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;

  while (element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //initialize funtion
  AN.initialize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="main">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="600px">Upgrade to modern browser in order to see this painting ;)</canvas>
</section>
```

Any idea on how to stop it from going back to center and make it stay in actual position?

Regards,
Iniestar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so I messed around quite a lot with your code so I apologise there.

Essentially, it comes down to two things. You aren't keeping track of the image's position correctly and are applying the wrong mathematics.

I noticed this immediately in your code:

```
var tx = position.x; //actual position of element for x
var ty = position.y; //actual position of element for y
```

Followed by this in your main loop:

```
tx = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * x;
ty = EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * y;
```

I'm assuming you're trying to take into account the position of tx, but you're overwriting it immediately, making it redundant! As for the maths, the easing is correct, but you're not really considering a new mouse position and how it has an effect on things.

Imagine you have a line running from the centre of the image to the mouse position at all times. When you factor in time, t, then you get the vector line equation: `r = r0 + tv`. This equation simply states that to get the point `r`, you supply a point `r0`, the direction vector `v` and some scalar `t`.

I modified your code to do exactly this,

```
x += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.x - x);
y += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.y - y);
```

`x` and `y` refer to the current position of your image. You always need to modify this so your image actually moves around correctly taking into account its last position. Since it is adding itself on, you can consider it as `r0` in terms of the equation. Your easing function provides the scalar value `t` while the position is simply the final point (i.e. your mouse coordinates). However, this position needs to be a vector and so by using `B - A` we can achieve that by using two endpoints - the mouse and image position.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74mnpgs7/)

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much. I appreciate the explanation, still didn't get it quite well because I'm not good with maths.. need to get some books to improve it.