# Add Easing to Following Image on mouseMove

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove, easing

I have created an Array of images that load randomly when the page is refreshed and follows the cursor with an `onmouseMove` function. And fades out after a certain amount of time. You can find a working example here — **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qupw2729/15/)**

I came across another **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28811456/4868587)** which supplied a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74mnpgs7/4/)** that allowed the image to follow the cursor as well as adding some easing to it. The overall flow and experience is much more appealing, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

What I would like to know is if it were to possible to implement easing to the design I have created? I've read that there are some easing plug-ins but I feel that my situation might be a little different, but I could be wrong, I am very inexperienced when it comes to JS and jQuery.

Any feedback on how I can achieve this would be appreciated.

**JS**

```
(function() {

  var pictures = ['http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/x-mark-4-xxl.png', 'http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/x-mark-xxl.png'];
  var selectedPicture = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictures.length);
  var randImg = pictures[selectedPicture];


  document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
      var imgFollow, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

    event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

    // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y
    // are, calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery
    // Calculate pageX/Y if missing and clientX/Y available
    if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
      eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
      doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
      body = eventDoc.body;

      event.pageX = event.clientX +
        (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
        (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
      event.pageY = event.clientY +
        (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
        (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
    }

    // Add an image to follow the cursor
    var pictures = new Array ('http://www.etamcru.com/pub/img/toolbar_x_icon.png', 'http://www.schultzlawoffice.com/img/icons/blue/arrow-up-50-white.png', 'http://www.fullscope.com/SiteCollectionImages/Icons/White/Right-Arrow-Icon.png');
    var selectedPicture = Math.floor(Math.random() * pictures.length);


    imgFollow = document.createElement('div');
    imgFollow.className = "imgFollow";
    imgFollow.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
    imgFollow.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
    imgFollow.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ randImg +')';
      console.log(randImg);
    document.body.appendChild(imgFollow);

    setTimeout(function () {
      imgFollow.className = "imgFollow fade-out"
    }, 200);

  }
})();
```

Comment: can't you define easing for `.fade-out`?? with CSS ??

Comment: Wouldn't that only apply an easing to the fading of images? I'm trying to make the image have that slight delay effect once the cursor moves and eases into position of the cursor, If you were to take a look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/74mnpgs7/4/ you'll notice the image is easing from the initial move - hopefully this makes sense? @RohitKumar